# override hashCode() with more than one attribute

Tags: java

I am trying to override hashCode and I know that there a x ways to implement it but I was wondering if I can do it like this:

```
String x;
String y;

(Code)

@Override
public int hashCode(){
   return ((x !=null ? x.hashCode() : 7)+ (y!=null ? y.hashCode() : 7));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are better ways to combine hash codes of multiple objects :

```
return Arrays.hashCode(new String[] {x, y});
```

or

```
return Objects.hash(x, y);
```

Comment: Thank you, but is it possible to implement it like I did?

Comment: `Objects.hash(x, y)` you mean

Comment: multiple objects... that are not arrays

Answer (score 3):

*Anything* deterministic in terms of the arguments is a valid implementation of `hashCode()`.  Your implementation isn't necessarily a *good* hash function, but it's a valid hash function.